# Can I combine a unit and acceptance test in codeception?

Tags: codeception

I have a codeception test that I am running that tests the front end submission of a form. I can do this with a simple acceptance test:

```
class ContactCest {
    public function testContactForm(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    }
}
```

But now I want to check the database to make sure that the correct data about the submission has been saved. In a unit test I could call `$I->assertEquals($expected, $found)`, but that doesn't seem to be available in the AcceptanceTester class. If I turn the test into a unit test class then everything else fails.

Is there any way to do an assertEquals() or the other asserts from within this class?

I found out that AcceptanceTester is a file built by codeception that was put into my test directory and it uses the trait:

```
use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;
```

I tried to add the additional trait:

```
use _generated\UnitTesterActions;
```

But I get a failure:

```
[RuntimeException] Action 'assertNotNull' can't be called
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use functions from the [`Asserts` module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts) in your acceptance tests, by enabling the module in your `acceptance.suite.yml` config.

But in your case, you can simply use `$I->seeInDatabase()`. 
You will have to enable the DB module and set up the database connection:

```
modules: 
    enabled: 
        - Asserts
        - DB: 
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'
         user: 'root'
         password: ''
         dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
         populate: true
         cleanup: true
         reconnect: true
```

See the documentation:
https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db